# WHMCS Smarty syntax to show total clients

Tags: syntax, smarty, whmcs

Is there a Syntax to display total clients in WHMCS (as a number)? If not, is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Please accept a reply when it solves the issue, so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this ode within your template files.
Just put this lines of code within your /templates/yourtemplate/yourfile.tpl

```
{php}
$query ="SELECT COUNT(id) from tblclients ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "total clients :".$data[0];

{/php}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getcontacts` command for getting the total numbr of clients in `WHMCS`. You might want to have a look at this document:

http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Get_Contacts